# Filtrar una columna en base a otra columna TABLEAU

Tags: tableau

Tengo una base de datos como esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo otra columna "Estado" donde hay valores "A" y "B". quiero contar cuantos Id (unicos) tengo en el estado "A" y cuantos en el estado "B", pero ambos deben estar en esta misma tabla.
Si pongo filtro va a filtrar para toda la tabla.

Como puedo hacer que en una columna cuente los ID (deben ser los unicos) del Estado A y en otra columna los ID del estado B?